# dependency in javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript code:

```
var r = {
    a1:function() {
        alert('hey!');
    },
    a2:this.a1
    /*,
    a3:r.a1, //<--Make an error when running
    a4:a1 //<--Make an error when running
    */ 
};
```

When executing `r.a1()` I get an alert but when executing `r.a2()` I get message:

```
TypeError: r.a2 is not a function
```

Why is it? How can I make this work in in one statement?

Comment: ..are you trying to define a "class", or you just want an object containing some functions..?

Comment: @redShadow: Class has no means in JavaScript. What do you mean??

Comment: I mean the class-like "instantiable" objects using ``function.prototype`` and as such, providing a context..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this`, in your definition does not refer to r, but to the actual context (probably `window`)

you should define it like this:

```
var r = {
   a1: function() {}
   /* a3: r, // Here r is not yet assigned. First the object is created, then its value
             // is assigned to r.
  */
};

r.a2 = r.a1;
r.a3 = r.a1;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use just the object literal, you can do it like this:

```
var r = {
    a1:function() {
        alert('hey!');
    },
    a2:function () {
        this.a1();
    }
};
```

The explanation is: in the object declaration, `this` refers to your current context - that is, the value of `this` in the function where you're declaring `r`.

As [BiAiB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13008669/182629) said, you can't use the name of the object inside the declaration (`r` in this case), because the variable is not assigned until the object is created.

If you assign a function to a member of the object, when that function gets called, the context will refer to your object, so `this` will be r.

Comment: @Alex Ciminian: I know this possibility and I tried to avoid it. I more intresting the reason I cannot access directly to this.a1 and need to wrap it with a function. What is the context inside the declaration and why a3:r.a1 throws an error.

Comment: The reason is the one I stated in my answer, when you say `a2: this.a1`, `this` is the context of the surrounding function, not the object you're declaring. If it's still not clear, I can try and come up with some other examples.